# Row of Images Responsive

Tags: css, html, row

I have been searching and cannot find a answer. Maybe I am just wording my search wrong but I am having trouble with making this row of images responsive.

http://jsfiddle.net/nunotmp/4W2Bc/

I have added the media query below

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
#teasercenter {
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
}
#teasercenter ul li img {
min-width:100%;
height:auto;
}

}
```

When resizing the window they do fall under each other but with a large white area and aligned to the left. Is there a way to get then to center as they fall? Maybe the way I structured the html is wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sorry Juan, I don't understand what you mean by 'responsive'.

Comment: By responsive I mean the images will drop below each other when the screen size gets smaller. You can adjust the jsfiddle window to get an idea. The images float beneath each other.

Comment: Its generally better to style all of your "shared" styles outside of the media queries, rather than style for desktop first and use media queries to winnow it down for narrower devices.

Comment: @cimmanon this bit of code just an additional to a responsive wordpress theme. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly know what you want to do, but probably you're looking for `display:inline-block;`, then the images would be at the center if they are underneath. You just have to make the parent element or body text-align:center; and it should work! Would be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4W2Bc/10/